# Java Process management

Tags: java, process

I have a process in Java which starts many daemons internally. While I shut down the original process, I need to perform a graceful shutdown by bringing down all the sub threads as well. How can I accomplish this in Java.

Sorry if the question is repititive. I have gone through so many links but have not been able to find a solution for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little more? The best option will depend on what they're doing, what kind(s) of systems you're deploying on, etc. Also, do you really mean separate processes (running in other JVMs), or just multiple threads in the same JVM?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. I mean multiple processes., running on same box though. But not as threads.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the threads to not be daemons, with setDaemon(false);

Comment: I cant run them as threads. They will be different processes only.

Comment: How do you start them?